# CurDir() returns several paths at random

Tags: vba, outlook

I have developed a `VBAProject` within `MicroSoft Outlook 2010` containing a couple of UserForms and a Module which holds the code to launch the UserForms.

I need to be able to retrieve the current directory of execution for this Macro/VBAProject for specific purposes and hence I use the `CurDir` function for that. The issue is that `CurDir` returns one of the following values sporadically:

`%USERPROFILE\Desktop\` 
`%USERPROFILE\Documents\` 
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\`

There are no specific patterns to identify when-what is returned. Each time the line `MsgBox CurDir` is executed, one of the above paths is returned and the next time it's a different one and so on. This happens with absolutely no changes in the code or in the way Outlook and the Macro have been launched.

I need to know how I can get the correct and consistent path wherein the program is getting executed, similar to `Shell.CurrentDirectory` in VBScript.

Comment: When you say `program` - do you mean Outlook or the VB Project? Either will be static, so why do you need to use `CurDir()` ?

Comment: `CurDir` gives you the directory from where the code is executed. If the code is executed from Desktop, you will get the `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\``

Comment: @PaulFrancis do you mean in VBA? I'm pretty sure `CurDir()` when used in Office returns the current _working_ directory, for instance in Excel you would use `ThisWorkbook.Path` to get the path where the code is running from, and `CurDir()` would not necessarily be the same path.

Comment: @SOofWXLS: I need the path where the VBAProject executes. Typically Macros sit in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook\VBAProject.OTM and I believe this is what you mean by the path being "static" -- but that is not seemingly where the code is getting executed, going by all the paths returned by CurDir.

Comment: @PaulFrancis: The code is technically not executed from the desktop, as this is a VBAProject and an Outlook Macro.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're assuming that CurDir returns the path of the code being executed, when this isn't the case. For example, use the `ChDir()` method and then use `CurDir` afterwards.

Comment: @SOofWXLS: So how would I use the equivalent of `ThisWorkbook.Path` in an Outlook Macro then? In order to get the path of the code being executed.

Comment: That's my point, Outlook will use the default path structure in windows (`%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook`), so there's no need to search for this it will be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `CurDir()` function returns the current path.

And

> It starts with the default user path, typically my-docs. If the user browses to a different path through the UI (e.g. Open/Save) `CurDir` will return that. In theory multiple instances of different Office apps could return a different `CurDir` at the same time.
>   `CurDir` for the host app can be changed with `ChDir`

---

You can use this code and `GetOutlookPath()` function:

```
Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, ByVal samDesired As Long, phkResult As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, lpType As Long, ByVal lpData As String, lpcbData As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long

Private Const REG_SZ As Long = 1
Private Const KEY_ALL_ACCESS = &H3F
Private Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Public Function GetOutlookPath() As String
    GetOutlookPath = GetOfficeAppPath("Outlook.Application")
End Function

Private Function GetOfficeAppPath(ByVal ProgID As String) As String
Dim lKey As Long
Dim lRet As Long
Dim sClassID As String
Dim sAns As String
Dim lngBuffer As Long
Dim lPos As Long

    'GetClassID
    lRet = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\Classes\" & ProgID & "\CLSID", 0&, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, lKey)
    If lRet = 0 Then
        lRet = RegQueryValueEx(lKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, "", lngBuffer)
        sClassID = Space(lngBuffer)
        lRet = RegQueryValueEx(lKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, sClassID, lngBuffer)
        'drop null-terminator
        sClassID = Left(sClassID, lngBuffer - 1)
        RegCloseKey lKey
    End If

    'Get AppPath
    lRet = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\Classes\CLSID\" & sClassID & "\LocalServer32", 0&, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, lKey)

    If lRet = 0 Then
        lRet = RegQueryValueEx(lKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, "", lngBuffer)
        sAns = Space(lngBuffer)
        lRet = RegQueryValueEx(lKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, sAns, lngBuffer)
        sAns = Left(sAns, lngBuffer - 1)
        RegCloseKey lKey
    End If

    'Sometimes the registry will return a switch beginning with "/" e.g., "/automation"
    lPos = InStr(sAns, "/")
    If lPos > 0 Then
        sAns = Trim(Left(sAns, lPos - 1))
    End If

    GetOfficeAppPath = sAns
End Function
```